# SQL Query for Optional Custom Paging, C# ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, sql, customization, objectdatasource

The  ***SQL Custom Paging Query*** for ObjectDataSource, allows each request to only provide data relevant to the particular page, increasing loading speed.

The question is ***how to make paging optional?***

```
string Query = @"
   DECLARE @PagedData int
   SET @PagedData = 1

   SELECT    
        CASE 
            WHEN @PagedData = 1 
            THEN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + _sortColumns + @") AS ResultRank, *

                FROM dbTable

                WHERE (FeatureString LIKE '%gold%')

                AS ProductsWithRowNumber WHERE ResultRank > 
                " + startIndex + " AND ResultRank <= (" + startIndex + " + " + pageSize + @"))

            ELSE (SELECT * FROM dbTable WHERE (FeatureString LIKE '%gold%'))  
        END";
```

The goal is for the SQL function to be able to get data only for that particular page, or it can turn off paging get all the relevant data.

Above is my attempt to use a CASE to switch whether the query is paged based on the value of the variable PagedData. However, this method ends in error.

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything, thank you.

Comment: what means 'fails'? any error message?

Comment: error: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: and can you get the final sentence, maybe a breakpoint, or saving in a text file, or a message box?

Comment: I think you want an `IF` not a `CASE` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL does not look exactly right but assuming it is correct, here is how to use an if statement:

```
 string Query = @"
DECLARE @PagedData int
SET @PagedData = 1

IF @PagedData = 1 
(
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + _sortColumns + @") AS ResultRank, *
   FROM dbTable
   WHERE (FeatureString LIKE '%gold%')
      AS ProductsWithRowNumber WHERE ResultRank > 
   " + startIndex + " AND ResultRank <= (" + startIndex + " + " + pageSize + @")
)
ELSE 
(
  SELECT * FROM dbTable WHERE (FeatureString LIKE '%gold%')
)";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: Ill check it and declare this the answer if it works, thank you for your insight\

Comment: AWESOME! I was told If Else statements couldnt be used in SQL, oh the frustration.. :)

Comment: @Java `IF ELSE` can't be used in Queries -- here we are using it in the batch processing language which is actually not SQL.  Technically like IF/ELSE you can't have variables or declare statements in SQL too.  Also note using IF statements can be really slow so be careful.